# I'm trying to get second heights salary but not able to fetch record from database

Tags: mysql, sql

`SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM Employee WHERE SALARY >= (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM Employee);`

Above is my SQL query, I try multiple time how to fetch the data of second heights salary.
But getting invalid response of query.

I'm expecting show the second heights salary from the 10k user. Those who have second heights salary. Please help to solve that. Its my task from interview.

Comment: in modern versions of mysql you would use rank or dense_rank or row_number functions for this (which one depends how you want ties handled)

Comment: You are basicly comparing the highest salary vs the highest salary right now, which will always give you the highest salary... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM Employee WHERE SALARY < (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM Employee);
```

replace your query